# how to activate telnet in windows 7 without administration

Tags: windows-7, telnet

How can I enable/activate commandline telnet without having admin privileges?  I don't wish to use putty. I wish to use native telnet that starts from commandline.

Comment: ...then you're probably out of luck.  Is there a particular reason that you do not want to use Putty?

Comment: Windows7 telnet client does not require admin rights. Works fine for me without running it with admin rights. Why do you think it need them?

Comment: Admin rights are required on Windows 7 when you try to enable telnet as described here: https://kb.ctera.com/article/how-to-open-a-telnet-session-on-windows-7-or-windows-8-os-16.html

Comment: The reason i cannot use putty is because, I am trying to using winpexpect (Python) to start a telnet session and expect the prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessarily the answer to activate telnet, but this does answer how to get telnet working from commandlline on windows 7 without having admin privileges and without putty.

Answer is pretty simple:

1. Install cygwin with inetutils for telnet http://www.question-defense.com/2010/11/30/install-telnet-using-cygwin-on-windows-7,
2. Add cygwin bin to my local env PATH variable https://superuser.com/questions/25037/change-environment-variables-as-standard-user-windows-7